How to adjust Opening Time in pine script
in this pine script code, Everything works fine in the Forex market. But when I switch to NQ and futures market the opening time with the selection of True Open, gets plotted at 19:00 instead of 18:00. can anyone suggest anything? The purpose of the code is to separate days in hourly timeframe. Everything is almost straightforward to read in the code.
//@version=5
indicator('Day Separator[Kourosh]', overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

// Input to select the opening time
openingTimeOption = input.string(defval="Midnight", title="Opening Time", options=["Midnight", "New York Open", "True Open"])

// Function to determine if it is the start of a new day
isNewDay() =>
    if (openingTimeOption == "New York Open")
        hour == 8 and minute == 0
    else if (openingTimeOption == "True Open")
        hour == 17 and minute == 0
    else
        hour == 0 and minute == 0

// Adjust the day of the week based on the selected opening time
adjustedDayOfWeek = dayofweek

if (openingTimeOption == "True Open") 
    adjustedDayOfWeek := (dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday) ? dayofweek.monday :
                         (dayofweek == dayofweek.monday) ? dayofweek.tuesday :
                         (dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday) ? dayofweek.wednesday :
                         (dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday) ? dayofweek.thursday :
                         (dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday) ? dayofweek.friday :
                         (dayofweek == dayofweek.friday) ? dayofweek.saturday :
                         dayofweek.sunday

// Fix for Monday plotting issue when True Open is selected
if (openingTimeOption == "True Open" and dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday)
    adjustedDayOfWeek := dayofweek.monday // Plot Monday at Sunday 18:00

// Get the current week number and year
currentWeek = weekofyear(timenow)
currentYear = year(timenow)

// Calculate the current bar's week number and year
barWeek = weekofyear(time)
barYear = year(time)

// Adjust for True Open: If Sunday 18:00 to 23:59 should be considered part of the next week (for Monday's plotting)
if (openingTimeOption == "True Open" and dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday and hour >= 18)
    barWeek := barWeek + 1  // Consider Sunday evening as the next week for plotting

// Check if the current bar is within the current week
inCurrentWeek = (barWeek == currentWeek) and (barYear == currentYear)

// Create an input option to select the plot time length
plotLengthOption = input.string(defval="Current Week", title="Plot Time Length", options=["Current Week", "All Time"])

// Determine if the current plot condition based on the selected option
plotCondition = plotLengthOption == "All Time" or (plotLengthOption == "Current Week" and inCurrentWeek)

// Define line style options
lineStyleOption = input.string(defval="Dotted", title="Line Style", options=["Solid", "Dashed", "Dotted"])

// Define line color options for Monday and midweek days
lineColorMonday = input.color(defval=color.red, title="Monday Line Color")
lineColorMidweek = input.color(defval=color.gray, title="Midweek Line Color")

// Define line extend options
lineExtendOption = input.string(defval="Extend", title="Line Extend", options=["Extend", "None"])

// Determine the line style
lineStyle = lineStyleOption == "Dashed" ? line.style_dashed : lineStyleOption == "Dotted" ? line.style_dotted : line.style_solid

// Determine the line extend
lineExtend = lineExtendOption == "Extend" ? extend.both : extend.none

// Plot vertical lines for each new day within the selected time length
if (isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek != dayofweek.monday)
    line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=high, x2=bar_index, y2=low, color=lineColorMidweek, width=1, style=lineStyle, extend=lineExtend)

if (isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.monday)
    line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=high, x2=bar_index, y2=low, color=lineColorMonday, width=1, style=lineStyle, extend=lineExtend)

// Add labels with the names of the days for each new day within the selected time length
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.sunday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Sun', textcolor=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), size=size.small)
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.monday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Mon', textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.small)
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.tuesday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Tue', textcolor=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), size=size.small)
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.wednesday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Wed', textcolor=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), size=size.small)
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.thursday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Thu', textcolor=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), size=size.small)
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.friday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Fri', textcolor=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), size=size.small)
plotshape(series=isNewDay() and plotCondition and adjustedDayOfWeek == dayofweek.saturday ? 1 : na, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), style=shape.arrowup, text='Sat', textcolor=color.new(#8d8e91, 0), size=size.small)


Forex and futures have different trading hours. One can trade Forex 24 hours a day, from Sunday 22:00 GMT until Friday 22:00 GMT. NQ futures are traded almost 24 hours from Sunday 22:00 GMT until Friday 21:00 GMT, and with daily break from 22:00 to 23:00 GMT. I did not try your code, but I guess that´s the reason for the different behaviour

I already have considered the timings and all. would you mind taking a look at the code?
